# Android app can`t connect to LAN server

Tags: android, linux

I am building android app that connects to tcp server via socket.
When I run the server (java server) on Windows, the app connect, send, receive etc. just fine, but when I run the server (same code) on linux (OpenSuse 13.2 kde desktop) The app can connect only on emulator. If I run it on my LG Magna it does not connect. I am using every internet permission I could find.

Answer (score 0):

You have to chceck if you can ping both devices. You have to get ip from android and from your serwer try to ping one from other. To android you can connect threw adb. But it will be ok if you will ping Android from Linux. I am quite shure that you wont be able.

Comment: I`ve just pinged the android device and it responded well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to connect to your server by putty/telnet - even from your serwer to check if your socket is opened.  If you wont't be able to open port maybe you have any info/warning/eroor when you are creating socket on serwer. If no what is the message when you are connecting maybe there is something wrong.

Comment: I can connect from java client. Only the android device can`t connect to this server and only if the server is on linux.

Comment: So you have to check both sides of connection, you have to implement errors warnings messages check. You have to find interfaces on whitch they are working maybe there is something wrong. Any info from this any warnings sockets are opened on both sides if not what is wrong ? maybe there will be some info in adb logs ?

Comment: no warnings in the logs, and the code seems fine since it is working on windows. Maybe linux has firewall that blocks android connections?

Comment: maybe but in this case you will be have info in linux logs that you are trying to connect. Here is topic how to add services to your firewall http://www.unixmen.com/quick-tip-allow-services-firewall-opensuse/      and one topic how to disable it http://insanelabs.com/linux/opensuse-disable-firewall-completely/   but i dont recomend this solution - you can do it only for test if necesarry.